# Rename thousands of pictures using their EXIF date

Tags: windows, data-recovery, exif

I know that every picture should contain some sort of information = [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif), what interests me is datetime, as I have now 20 000 pictures on disk unsorted, recovered from lost partition.

Example of healthy photo internal information:

[image: image info]

I wish there was a way to sort those photos by timestamp, is there? If so, what software could I use?

**EDIT:**

The timestamp should be extracted from the [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) information.

New file naming should look similar to the following example:

> ```
> 2017-08-17_15.10.jpg
> ```

So far I use integrated Windows 10 tools to image view, edit and so on. No third-party application.

I am looking for an application of such capability.

**EDIT2:**

- The lost partition was of type NTFS, MBR, so no backup table.
- The drive is a SATA HDD.

**EDIT3:**

I have already recovered all the data, but the question is different: How to name the files by EXIF information.

**EDIT4:**

Despite I work on both Windows and Linux, I wish this work to be done on Windows, filesystem on the drive was NTFS.

Comment: What OS must it run on? NTFS suggests Windows. If Linux is an option (I don't know if those tools are available on Windows), what you describe is part of my usual "post-processing" after having edited photos from an "event", including adjusting the time stamps and extracting some data from Exif (such as comments and GPS information). Need to check my scripts for what tools I've used there, if it's relevant.

Comment: As read-write on NTFS is no big deal even on Linux, that sounds like I should propose my Linux solution then? As now you've tagged your question `windows`, which means it *must* run on Windows. Further, it comes without GUI (pure scripting/CLI solution). That fine with you?

Comment: A couple of useful links on the topic: https://del.icio.us/thelazza/exif

Comment: By the way "The lost partition was of type NTFS, MBR, so no backup table" -> Have you tried RecuperaBit (of which I am the developer)? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rename photos using EXIF data?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27381/how-can-i-rename-photos-using-exif-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [exiv2](http://exiv2.org/). Hans-Henry Jakobsen has written [a very neat tutorial](https://pario.no/2008/01/14/rename-image-files-according-to-exif-date/) about it. Here's a quote:

> **Linux**
>
> ```
> exiv2 -r'%Y%m%d-%H%M_:basename:' rename $(ls)
> ```
>
> **Windows (from the command prompt)**
>
> ```
> exiv2.exe -r %Y%m%d-%H%M_:basename: rename d*
> ```
>
> **Windows (in a MS-DOS batch file)**
>
> ```
> exiv2.exe -r %%Y%%m%%d-%%H%%M_:basename: rename d*
> ```

The markers you need to use are `%Y`, `%m` and `%d`. You can add hyphens or dots in between them as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [**Bulk Rename Utility**](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk). It is a freeware, GUI tool for Windows. It can rename files in a variety of ways.

To rename based on the EXIF date/time, look at the option for *Auto Date (8)*. If you set this to *Taken (Original)* it will use the EXIF tags. You can specify how the date/time should be formatted, and what separators between segments.

[image: Bulk Rename Utility screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

While I'm on Linux and have my solutions scripted, I just checked and the main components are available for Windows, too: **[Exiftool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/exiftool/)** and **[JHead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).** This is a command-line utility, so you need to run it from your `cmd` prompt. Useful commands include:

```
jhead -ft <image> # set the file's time stamp from Exif data
jhead -n<format_string> <image> # rename the file according to the format
```

The latter you can run on the entire directory:

```
jhead -n%Y-%m%d_%H.%M *.jpg # 2017-08-17_15.10.jpg
```

Those are the command you will need according to your question, but the mentioned tools can do a lot more – e.g. rotating the images, adding comments, and the like. I use them a lot for batch processing of my photos.

Comment: Always glad to help! As you can read and write Exif with those tools, I've set up a bunch of scripts around them. Including creating an index with location details and map links whenever location data are present :)

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible application that could do it:

[AmoK Exif Sorter](http://www.amok.am/en/freeware/amok_exif_sorter/)

After installation of 64-bit version, there's bad link to Java in the created shortcut, you need to change it, for instance in my case the correct path is:

> ```
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe" -Xmx256m -jar "C:\Program Files\AmoK Exif Sorter\exifsorter.jar"
> ```

It works just fine for my case.